# Bootstrap 5 carousel with multiple items

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, bootstrap-5

I'm new to Bootstrap and I'm doing an ecommerce template for learning Bootstrap 5.

Is there a way to make the Bootstrap 5 carousel to show multiple slides at the same time like a products slider with left and right arrow?

If yes how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want [a Bootstrap carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/).

```html
<section class="pt-5 pb-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <h3 class="mb-3">Carousel cards title </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 text-right">
        <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 mr-1" href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 " href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517760444937-f6397edcbbcd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=42b2d9ae6feb9c4ff98b9133addfb698">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532712938310-34cb3982ef74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3d2e8a2039c06dd26db977fe6ac6186a">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532771098148-525cefe10c23?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3f317c1f7a16116dec454fbc267dd8e4">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532715088550-62f09305f765?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=ebadb044b374504ef8e81bdec4d0e840">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506197603052-3cc9c3a201bd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=0754ab085804ae8a3b562548e6b4aa2e">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=ee8417f0ea2a50d53a12665820b54e23">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532777946373-b6783242f211?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=8ac55cf3a68785643998730839663129">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532763303805-529d595877c5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=5ee4fd5d19b40f93eadb21871757eda6">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE:**

An example with four columns. It is necessary just edit classes of div and edit class from `col-md-4` to `col-md-3`. Class `row` [can have 12 columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/):

```html
<section class="pt-5 pb-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <h3 class="mb-3">Carousel cards title </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 text-right">
        <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 mr-1" href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 " href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517760444937-f6397edcbbcd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=42b2d9ae6feb9c4ff98b9133addfb698">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532712938310-34cb3982ef74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3d2e8a2039c06dd26db977fe6ac6186a">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532712938310-34cb3982ef74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3d2e8a2039c06dd26db977fe6ac6186a">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
              </div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517760444937-f6397edcbbcd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=42b2d9ae6feb9c4ff98b9133addfb698">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532712938310-34cb3982ef74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3d2e8a2039c06dd26db977fe6ac6186a">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532712938310-34cb3982ef74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3d2e8a2039c06dd26db977fe6ac6186a">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517760444937-f6397edcbbcd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=42b2d9ae6feb9c4ff98b9133addfb698">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532712938310-34cb3982ef74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3d2e8a2039c06dd26db977fe6ac6186a">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532712938310-34cb3982ef74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3d2e8a2039c06dd26db977fe6ac6186a">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: and how to make it responsive showing ony one slide on mobile?

Comment: @Epilol  It is already responsive. You can choose what should be put into `<div class="carousel-item">` by putting desired count of images

Comment: i don't understand how this is working. you make 3 x carousel items whit a row and 3 x columns inside and if i run the snippet i see on full screen the slider working how i need  but if i make it on mobile views i se 3 items in column and if click the arrow they slide all 3 and this i not what i want. i need to make on mobile 1 row showing 1 slide and whit other 4 slide showing 1 per time... in the desktop views ii need 1 row showing 3 slide in the same momente sliding whit other 2 slide.

Comment: @Epilol it looks here what you want [How to make carousel with two pictures in computer display to 1 picture in mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40393558/how-to-make-carousel-with-two-pictures-in-computer-display-to-1-picture-in-mobil)

Comment: yes ok but in your example on desktop when i click the arrow it slide 3 slide at the same time... i need to slide only 1 slide left or right not 3

Comment: @Epilol you can delete or add unnecessary images from `<div class="carousel-item">`. Try to delete images and you will get desired result

Comment: This only works if you have exactly multiple of 3 number of images to show

Comment: @Inc33 If `col-md-4` class is used then yeah you can add just 3 images. However, you can  use `col-md-3` class to have 4 items in your carousel. Please, see my updated answer.

Comment: Then to correct my comment: This only works if you have exactly multiple of N images to show. What do you do if you need to show 3 at a time with 5 total images, and on mobile 2 at a time with the same total of 5 images? In real life scenario this is useless

Comment: @Inc33 you can create them dynamically and apply appropriate classes. An example [through Angular framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881422/dynamic-population-of-bootstrap-4-carousel-via-angular-4-not-displaying-images)