# How can I make multiple items appear on a bootstrap 5 carousel slide?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I have a [bootstrap 5 carousel with controls](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/). My desired output is a slideshow with 2 items per slide and I would like to scroll through one image at a time.

From here:
[image]
To here:
[image]

The problem with solutions I have found which use the bootstrap grid system like the ones posed on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67120095/bootstrap-5-carousel-with-multiple-items) are that they rely on the correct multiple of items to work and they scroll two items per click, not one. A lot of the solutions I have found online are buggy or overcomplicated.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this ?

```
<div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active ">
            <div class="col-12 row">
                <div class="col-6" style="background-color: yellow; height: 10vh;"></div>
                <div class="col-6 " style="background-color: blue; height: 10vh;"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-12 row">
                <div class="col-6" style="background-color: red; height: 10vh;"></div>
                <div class="col-6 " style="background-color: green; height: 10vh;"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
   
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
```

Comment: if true , you must learn again for grid flexbox in bootrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/ and struktur html